# AlarmManager и push-уведомления

Tags: android

Ув. программисты, я по-старинке для отображения нотификаций (push-уведомлений) именно в определенное время (допусти в 18:10 каждого дня) использую связку AlarmManager-Broadcastreceiver-Notifications.
Но, в последнее время я стал замечать неадекватную работу этой связки (то не вовремя срабатывает, то вообще пропускает срабатываение), в связи с чем у меня возник вопрос: может появились новые способы показать уведомление в определенное???Например, я слышал про Job Schedule, но так и не понял, как запускать уведомления по времени...

И второй вопрос: я знаю, что в Oreo для уведомлений используются некие каналы. Вопрос: будут ли на API26+ работать уведомления построенные старым способом?

Подскажите, плз...
Заранее вас благодарю!

Код:

```
onTimeSet(18,10)
public void onTimeSet(int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 1);

        if (calNow.after(calSet) == true) {
            // Если выбранное время на сегодня прошло,
            // то переносим на завтра
            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        setAlarm(calSet);
    }

    private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {



        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmMessage.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pendingIntent);


    }
```

Код БроадКаст ресивера приводить не буду, так как он у всех одинаковый.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте WorkManager - удобное использование, API 14-22 это AlarmManager + BR , 23+ API JobSheduler , использует все сам, подстраивается под версию, да и работать с ним проще и удобнее, только там есть некоторые ограничения в использовании по поводу времени, например нельзя устанавливать повторяющийся цикл, если он меньше 15 мин. Связано с тем, что в последнее время разработчики максимально пытаются урезать то, что жрет заряд батареи.

П.С. Могу скинуть примеры использования

Comment: Если можно скиньте, пожалуйста, примеры... Основной вопрос в том, что мне нужно, чтобы уведомление было показано в 18:10 раз в сутки. Как этого добиться с JobSheduler я не знаю, так как я понял данный фреймворк обеспечивает срабатывание по уровню батареи, наличия или отсутствия Инет-соединения, но именно указать в нем время появления уведомления нельзя...